# Can JQuery Mobile UI provide a user-created attribute table for a user-created point feature?

Tags: mobile, jquery

I'm looking into using the [JQuery Mobile UI](http://jquerymobile.com/), and I would like the user of the app to be able to create their own point on the map and add a few short attributes. Any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, many people do use JQuery Mobile together with their choice of mapping API. I use both google maps and ESRI's JavaScript web mapping APIs with JQuery Mobile. If you are planning on doing it with the Google Maps v3 API here is a [great set of examples](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-mobile-example.html).

Comment: @dkroy do you have any examples using the ArcGIS JS API and jQuery Mobile?